# can't find or load class: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

Tags: macos, hadoop

I installed hadoop on my mac, I followed the hadoop installation step by step

when I execute the `hdfs namenode -format`

hadoop always return me the error 
`can't find or load class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode`

here is my /etc/profile:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/contents/home
 export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
 export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
 export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0
 export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME:$PATH
```

I have no idea where is incorrect, could anyone kindly help me have a check ?

Comment: Hey, DId you find the answer for this?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Please check the core-site.xml in /etc/hadoop/conf/ and edit it properly as follows: 
core-site.xml:

> ```
>   <configuration>
>        <property>
>            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
>            <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
>        </property>
>    </configuration>
> ```

2) Please change the path to 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH
and source the profile again.

Comment: Hi,is your installation a tarball installation or a package installation?? Also could you check if your classpath is set properly for hadoop using the "hadoop classpath" . Check if the path includes all the directories with the hadoop jars.